# how change rgb color of points in plt.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to change the color of the dots in this order (red, green, blue)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot ([0,10,20], [0, 10,20], 'or--')
plt.show ()
```

all three points are red, how can i change the color of the points in plt.plot.

for example something like

```
plt.plot ([0,10,20], [0, 10,20], 'o--', point1 = [255,0,0], point2 = [0,255,0], point3 = [0,0,255 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

`plot.plot` plots the lines, if you want color points, you should use `plt.scatter`:

```
# scatter takes (r,g,b) values between (0,1)
colors = np.array([[24,88,174],[255,0,0],[0,255,0]])/255

# lines
plt.plot([0,10,20], [0,10,20],'--')

# scatter has `c` option for colors
plt.scatter([0,10,20], [0, 10,20], c=colors)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this code, what ever x and y are, the points will be colored in this pattern: red, green, blue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,10,20,30,35,60]
y = [0,5,40,35,15,40]

c = 'or--'
while len(x) > 0:
    plt.plot(x,y,c)
    if c == 'or--': c = 'og--'
    elif c == 'og--': c = 'ob--'
    else: c = 'or--'
    x.pop(0)
    y.pop(0)
plt.show ()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: what happens if I want an arbitrary color eg [24,88,174]

Comment: You can use hex values: '#008000' is a shade of green.